# How do we phrase a Suggestion to fight unarmed to be reasonable?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, combat, dnd-adventurers-league

Our party is about to fight an ogre and his allies.

If we could convince the ogre to fight unarmed - that would (theoretically) drop its damage to just 1 point of unarmed damage (per the PHB) plus its strength bonus.

Is there any example in an existing adventure or in previous Crawford's rulings of a Suggestion being phrased in such a way that disarming and fighting unarmed was considered "reasonable" as per the spell requirements?

Answer (score 6):

Remember the rules:

1. The DM describes the environment.
2. The players describe what they want to do.
3. The DM narrates the results of the adventurers’
   actions.

> The suggestion must be worded in such a manner as to make the course of action sound reasonable.

"Look at how strong you are and how weak I am - surely you can beat me with just your bare hands?"

We are now at Step 3 "The DM narrates the results of the [suggestion]". The DM should be asking themselves "Is this reasonable?" Given that Ogres have "Legendary Stupidity" [MM], are Large (and the PC is presumably Small or Medium) it sounds pretty reasonable to me. Against an Oni, not so much.

Comment: Maybe elaborate a little bit more on how role-playing and the Suggestion spell can intertwine to achieve the intended effect?